# Determine Function signature

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++

Given an address of function, how to determine its signature?

```
    DWORD funcAddr = 0x63001023; // arbitrary address
    char[MAX] signature = ?      // what algorithm can be devised?
```

The reason for it is as follows:

```
there is a exe say Calc.exe, once the process starts on pc "A"

my exe intercepts the creation of process and sends the signal to pc"B" 

where the same calc.exe starts. 

then the users presses the digits every click, movement, 

internal process of suppose addition is passed on from pc"A" to pc"B" where 

it is getting virtualized. so all resources to manipulate the function arguments

are present on pc"B", all i need is a perfect signature......

so even the fundamentally dangerous activity of hooking unknown dll becomes "kind-of" safe...
```

please do not suggest any third - party libraries.

Comment: Neither C nor C++ support reflection.  You could dig this info out of debug info, the .pdb and DbgHelp api required.

Comment: @ Hans: How to use the DbgHelp api? would you please deposit a sample code....

Comment: @ Hans: Unfortunately, theres no debug info or .pdb

Comment: @rohank Trying to make some hack? :)

Comment: @ Kiril: No.... I work on Application virtualization. currently i am virtualizing an erp....

Comment: @ kiril: so, how do you propose to take the start??

Comment: You have to contact the people who wrote the software so they can tell you what the function signature is. The information is not recorded anywhere.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Lets focus on the method.

Comment: There is no method. The information does not exist in the exe. It is in the pdb, but you say that you don't have it.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I mean lets arrange available knowledge to form a method

Comment: The available knowledge is in the PDB, in the source code, and in the brains of the people who wrote the software, none of which you claim to have access to. Otherwise, you're stuck with reverse-engineering. And even if you had the function signature, you still don't know what the parameters mean. Suppose you figured out that the function takes an `int` and returns an `int`. Now what?

Comment: @Raymond: how to figure it out programmatically?

Comment: You can programmatically extract it from the PDB via `dbghelp`, as noted in the answer you already accepted. But knowing the function signature does not let you know how to call the function. You still haven't explained what you intend to do once you figure out the function signature. I.e., what is the scenario?

Comment: @RaymondChen: As I have posted earlier I am currently virtualizing an ERP. Once I get the function Signature, I will be able to know the datatypes of the function arguments also their exact count the datatype of return value. Hence, I would be able to develop an exact and specific engine to initialize hooking in unknown dll.

Comment: Even if you figure out the datatypes, you won't know what they *mean*. The function takes an `int`. Is that `int` a bitmask of flags? Is it a count of customers? Is it a buffer size? (In other words, knowing the prototype still doesn't solve the problem.) And hooking an unknown DLL is fundamentally dangerous. You will never get this to work with 100% confidence.

Comment: @RaymondChen: dats fine but i dont have to know it well. The reason for it is as follows: there is a exe say Calc.exe, once the process starts on pc "A" my exe intercepts the creation of process and sends the signal to pc"B" where the same calc.exe starts. then the users presses the digits every click, movement, internal process of suppose addition is passed on from pc"A" to pc"B" where it is getting virtualized

Comment: @RaymondChen: so all resources to manipulate the function arguments are present on pc"B", all i need is a perfect signature......so even the fundamentally dangerous activity becomes "kind-of" safe...

Comment: Now you're contradicting yourself. You said that you didn't have the PDB in the third comment. If you have the PDB, then use Ajay's answer: Use the `DbgHelp` functions to extract the function signature.

Comment: No, i am actually not contradicting because on pc"A" there is no resource except the dlls so as on pc"B". There fore to use pc"B" dlls i should know the exact moment a certain function is called and then i intercept it and pass the parameters to dll function in pc"B".

Comment: @RaymondChen: As you have participated for this long on the question.... i request you to please try to find out a direction... its challenging... and i am sure this problem can be dealt with.

Comment: The direction is (and always has been) (1) Use the PDB and the `DbgHelp` functions, or (2) Use the source code, or (3) Get help from the vendor. Methods (2) and (3) come with semantic information. Method (1) does not. But if you claim that you don't need semantic information, then that's great. Go with #1.

Comment: @rohank: I think this is an XY problem. You want to do X, and you think Y is the best way of doing so. Instead of asking about X, you ask about Y. In this case, `Y` appears to be figuring out the signature of a function from a binary - but I'm not sure what `X` is. Are you just trying to replicate every user interaction with your process (say: `calc.exe`) on another computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first thing first - It is not easy. You may give up.

You need to use [DbgHelp functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms679291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), particularly under **Symbol Handler**. 
You need to identify the calling-convention, the argument and return types it takes. Need to worry about the types (UDF) it takes. Then make those types, pass them to function, and call the function with appropriate calling convention.

`RunDLL32.EXE` is one of the tool that loads a function, looks up the function, <strike>its types</strike> and makes up a call. Try running following on command prompt:

`rundll32 user32.dll LockWorkStation`

Read up some articles on API Hooking, specifically one from Jeffery Ritcher.

Comment: Rundll does not try to figure out the prototype. It assumes a particular prototype, and if the functions doesn't have that prototype (LockWorkstation doesn't) then you get stack corruption and undefined behavior.

Comment: Mr. Chen even took the time to write [an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx) in 2004 on why it's wrong to use rundll32 with LockWorkStation. And [another](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/09/10208136.aspx).

Comment: that's correct, i am not challenging any persons insight on the subject... just trying to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Yes, RunDLL32 doesn't use symbol or debugging information, it just loads the function and calls as if it was having WinMain signature.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that.

However you can store [`boost::function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/function.html) with same signature and make a `map` of function address and boost::function object

Its safer to store function pointer instead of raw address in program.

Comment: plz direct me to algorithm. I cant use 3rd party library.

Comment: Thats why I said `However`. `boost::function` is a typed callback type. and comes from boost. and its not an algorithm, its a structure in C++11 there is `std::function`.